# Is the service pack required for the C++ runtime if the compiler has the service pack installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

If I compile a dll file using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010 SP1, will the client PCs still be able to run the dll even though they have C++ 2010 runtime installed and not C++ 2010 SP1 runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No. Think about it: if the old runtime was sufficient, why would Microsoft even release a new SP1 runtime package?